# This script will automatically restart the Tomcat when it exceeds 95% of physical memory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, scripting

It is not the solution but if a patch while we investigate because our Tomcat is filling memory

Comment: It is a solution that is not on internet :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
porcentaje=95
usoMemoria=$(ps aux | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | awk '{printf ("%.0f", $4)}')
if [ $usoMemoria -ge $porcentaje ]; then
    echo "Se ha superado el tope (95%) de memoria que se ha establecido para el Tomcat. Se procede a su reinicio automatico"
    echo "$(date)"
    echo "Comenzando..."
    service tomcat7 restart
    echo "Terminando Script..."
fi

exit 0
```

---

Enjoy it!! Greetings from Spain!!!!!! :D :)